# Windows XP - Restarting frequently

Tags: multi-boot

I had shortly installed a theme pack downloaded from internet to make windows xp look like windows 7. After installing the application it requested for a reboot for which I allowed. But after restarting the computer, it shows my wallpaper and then it again restarts without showing no further content. What should I do now?
The theme pack I used was named "hawo_red_7_for_xp_by_philipxd-d3dkjmj.rar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the issue reoccur when you start your machine in safe mode ?

If it doesnt occur in safe mode, there should be a third party service associated with the package. Disable it by going to msconfig->Services and using the "Hide all Microsoft Services" option, find out which third party service it is. After disabling it, restart the machine in normal mode and uninstall the package since it might be corrupted. Download a similar package and try installing it again.

If it reoccurs in safe mode and there is no third party service associated with the package,there might have been OS files that have been compromised. To troubleshoot this, boot using your Windows XP DVD/ISO and go to the recovery console and open a command prompt.
Here, type in the following command, but replace "C:" with the letter of the drive where your Windows XP is installed:

sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows

You can also try reverting back to a previous system restore point.

Comment: My computer is not starting. It does not shows any content. It just shows welcome screen and tends to restart. So where can I find the msconfig?

Comment: Vaibhav, please use the second scenario that i mentioned and use the sfc command after you go to the recovery console and let me know what happens.

Comment: Ya, your method works. I had restored my system to a previous restore point which I created earlier. Now my system is running well. Thanks.